# How do I apply an Ansible with_items loop to the included tasks?

Tags: ansible

The [documentation for `import_tasks`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/import_tasks_module.html) mentions

> Any loops, conditionals and most other keywords will be applied to the included tasks, not to this statement itself.

This is exactly what I want. Unfortunately, when I attempt to make `import_tasks` work with a loop

```
- import_tasks: msg.yml
  with_items:
    - 1
    - 2
    - 3
```

I get the message

> ERROR! You cannot use loops on 'import_tasks' statements. You should use 'include_tasks' instead.

I don't want the `include_tasks` behaviour, as this applies the loop to the included file, and duplicates the tasks. I specifically want to run the first task for each loop variable (as one task with the standard `with_items` output), then the second, and so on. How can I get this behaviour?

---

Specifically, consider the following:

Suppose I have the following files:

playbook.yml

```
---                       

- hosts: 192.168.33.100
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - include_tasks: msg.yml
    with_items:
      - 1
      - 2
```

msg.yml

```
---

- name: Message 1
  debug:
    msg: "Message 1: {{ item }}"

- name: Message 2
  debug:
    msg: "Message 2: {{ item }}"
```

I would like the printed messages to be

> Message 1: 1
>   Message 1: 2
>   Message 2: 1
>   Message 2: 2

However, with `import_tasks` I get an error, and with `include_tasks` I get

> Message 1: 1
>   Message 2: 1
>   Message 1: 2
>   Message 2: 2

Comment: Please rephrase your requirements... with some example maybe?

Comment: I have many tasks in msg.yml. If I use include_tasks, it runs task 1 with item 1, then task 2 with item 1, then task 3... I want task 1 with item 1, then task 1 with item 2, then task 1 with item 3...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add a `with_items` loop taking a list to every task in the imported file, and call `import_tasks` with a variable which you pass to the inner `with_items` loop. This moves the handling of the loops to the imported file, and requires duplication of the loop on all tasks.

---

Given your example, this would change the files to:

playbook.yml

```
---

- hosts: 192.168.33.100
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - import_tasks: msg.yml
    vars:
      messages:
        - 1
        - 2
```

msg.yml

```
---

- name: Message 1
  debug:
    msg: "Message 1: {{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ messages }}"

- name: Message 2
  debug:
    msg: "Message 2: {{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{ messages }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. `include`/`import` statements operate with task files as a whole.

So with loops you'll have:

```
Task 1 with Item 1
Task 2 with Item 1
Task 3 with Item 1
Task 1 with Item 2
Task 2 with Item 2
Task 3 with Item 2
Task 1 with Item 3
Task 2 with Item 3
Task 3 with Item 3
```

Comment: But truth be told the phrasing in the docs states the opposite. Someone who wrote that was too imaginative.

Comment: Or not enough ;)