# How to loop vars in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I am trying to import one ansible playbook `(test.yml)` into another `(test2.yml)`

In `test.yml` I have a variable assign in vars which is like below.

```
  - import_playbook: "{{ lookup('ini', 'COMMON_SCRIPTS section=ANSIBLE file={{ configFile }}') }}/test2.yml"
    vars:
      section: "ABC"
      section: "xyz"
      section: "def"
    tags:
      - copy
```

and the test2.yml is like below

```
- hosts: "LINUX"
  become: "{{ lookup('ini', 'ANSIBLE_BECOME section=ANSIBLE file={{ configFile }}') }}"
  vars:
    software: "{{ lookup('ini', 'TOMCATS section={{ section }} file={{ configFile }}').split(',') }}"
```

I am struggling with the syntax of looping the vars inside the section. I want to run the test2.yml playbook thrice so that it will pick all the three values of section variable.

I am blocked. Can I get help on this please?

Comment: you cannot loop `import_playbook` nor send vars or asign tags to it. Please see the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_playbook_module.html). What your are looking for IMO is [`include_tasks`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html). Also check the [loops documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html)

Comment: I am able to send one var to it.

Comment: One more problem is that you are overwriting the `section` variable, and it will hold **only** the last value `def`.

Comment: yes that is what is happening

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352361/how-do-i-apply-an-ansible-with-items-loop-to-the-included-tasks) might be useful.

Comment: Thanks @Seshadri_C the answer really helped.