# Execute multiple tasks one by one for a block in a role

Tags: ansible

I am creating an Ansible role to update hosts configured in a cluster. There are 3 'roles' defined in this PSA architecture.

```yaml
host-1 # primary
host-2 # secondary
host-3 # secondary
host-4 # secondary
host-5 # arbiter
```

I want to configure Ansible to execute a block of tasks, one by one per host, if the host is a secondary. But in that same block, execute a single task as the primary

E.g:

```yaml
- name: remove host from cluster
  shell: command_to_remove

- name: update
  yum:
    state: latest
    name: application

- name: add host to cluster
  shell: command_to_add

- name: verify cluster
  shell: verify cluster
  when: primary
```

The use of `serial` would be perfect here, but that isn't supported for a `block`.

The result of Ansible should be:

```yaml
TASK [remove host from cluster]
changed: [host-2]

TASK [update]
changed: [host-2]

TASK [add host from cluster] 
changed: [host-2]

TASK [verify cluster] 
changed: [host-1]

# rinse and repeat for host-3
TASK [remove host from cluster]
changed: [host-3]

TASK [update]
changed: [host-3]

TASK [add host from cluster] 
changed: [host-3]

TASK [verify cluster] 
changed: [host-1]

# and so on, until host-4
```

Comment: Separate the tasks which should be used as serial, launch them in a different play targeting your secondary hosts using the `serial` keyword. You could do that by putting those task in a specific task file in your role and use the `tasks_from` attribute of [`include_role`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html#parameter-tasks_from) or [`import_role`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_role_module.html#parameter-tasks_from)

Comment: Since I'm creating a role, I don't want to create a different play.

Comment: You can use the role twice targeting a different file in `tasks`. See the doc above. `serial` is only supported at play level. I don't know any other way to meet your above requirement.

Comment: You can also make it a group of tasks in a separate file and loop over an `import_tasks`, even in a role, I believe. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47354004/2123530

Comment: It seems Ansible is too limited. Both comments do not accomplish my need...

Answer (score 0):

While it might not be "correct" in some cases, you could put a hostvar to declare a sort of "profile" for each of the hosts, then do an "include_tasks" with a profile.yaml based on that, then inside that profile.yaml put your tasks.

I do something similar with a playbook I use to configure a machine based on a profile declared on ansible invocation.

This playbook is invoked on the laptop being configured, so it uses localhost, but you could use it remotely with some tweaks

`hosts.yaml`

```
all:
    hosts:
      localhost:
        ansible_connection: local
    vars:
      profile: all
```

`playbook.yaml`

```
- hosts: all

  tasks:
  ...
  - name: Run install tasks
    include_role:
      name: appinstalls
  ...
```

`roles/appinstalls/tasks/main.yaml`

```
- name: Include tasks for profile "all"
  include_tasks: profile_all.yml
  when: 'profile == "all"'

- name: Include tasks for profile "office"
  include_tasks: profile_office.yml
  when: 'profile == "office"'
```

`roles/appinstalls/tasks/profile_all.yml`

```
- name: Run tasks for profile "all"
  include_tasks: "{{ item }}.yml"
  with_items:
    - app1
    - app2
    - app3
    - app4
```

`roles/appinstalls/tasks/profile_office.yml`

```
- name: Run tasks for profile "all"
  include_tasks: "{{ item }}.yml"
  with_items:
    - app1
    - app2
    - app3
    - app4
    - office_app1
    - office_app2
    - office_app3
    - office_app4
```

When invoked using:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i hosts.yaml -K
```

It will run using the default profile "all". If invoked using

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i hosts.yaml -K -e profile=office
```

It will run using the "office" profile instead

What I like about this method, is that all the includes happen in one go, rather than as you go along:

```
TASK [appinstalls : Run tasks for profile "office"] ******************************************************************************************************************************************
included: /home/blenderfox/machine-setup/files/roles/appinstalls/tasks/app1.yml for localhost => (item=app1)
included: /home/blenderfox/machine-setup/files/roles/appinstalls/tasks/app2.yml for localhost => (item=app2)
included: /home/blenderfox/machine-setup/files/roles/appinstalls/tasks/app3.yml for localhost => (item=app3)
included: /home/blenderfox/machine-setup/files/roles/appinstalls/tasks/app4.yml for localhost => (item=app4)
included: /home/blenderfox/machine-setup/files/roles/appinstalls/tasks/office_app1.yml for localhost => (item=office_app1)
included: /home/blenderfox/machine-setup/files/roles/appinstalls/tasks/office_app2.yml for localhost => (item=office_app2)
included: /home/blenderfox/machine-setup/files/roles/appinstalls/tasks/office_app3.yml for localhost => (item=office_app3)
included: /home/blenderfox/machine-setup/files/roles/appinstalls/tasks/office_app4.yml for localhost => (item=office_app4)
```

So in your case, you could put your tasks in the equivalent of the `profile_all` or `profile_office`

This method has no fancy stuff and it makes it easier to tack on future changes.

It fully allows each profile to independently evolve from the other -- just change the list in each of the `Run tasks for profile` block

Comment: I've read this answer a few times. It seems it doesn't answer my question, and is quite complex to understand.

Comment: It's a way to allow you to put tasks by "profile" which you indicate when you start ansible. So on your primary host you would run with `-e profile=primary` and on your secondary, you would run with `-e profile=secondary`. Then inside the playbook, you can configure what tasks you want to run and in what order when a specific profile is set.

Perhaps a real-life example might help: https://gitlab.com/blenderfox/pixelbook-fedora-setup -- This repo contains a version of the example above, that I use to configure a pixelbook running fedora. The playbook is in the `files/` folder